# Opposite to encodeURIComponent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, urlencode

Is there an opposite API to `encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript? Suppose you have a String with a bunch of `%25` etc in it for URI purposes. Is there an API which un-encodeURI it?

Thanks.

Comment: ... `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: That's an answer. My bad for not realising it. Add it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to the docs on MDN for [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) you will see a section that shows you the related methods

> ### See also
>
> - decodeURI
> - [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)
> - encodeURI

A good resource helps you out with questions like this.